# Add to Symfony form action

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4, symfony-forms

I've created a page with tabs (using bootstrap), and all tabs have their own form. And they all work well. My problem is when I get a form error, I want to open the tab that the error is on.

My current controller code:

```
public function add(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response {

    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER');

    $entityAdd = new \App\Entity\add();
    $form = $this->createForm(\App\Form\Add::class, $entityAdd);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
```

Function in AddFormType.php

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add(...)
                ->add(...)
                ->add(...)
                ->getForm()
        ;
    }
```

I'm not creating the form myself, I'm using symfony form components but I'm not sure how to modify the form method to add the form hash (eg. /add#list-tab1) to the form method.

```
{{ form_start(AddForm) }}

{{ form_row(AddForm.name1) }}
{{ form_row(AddForm.name2) }}
{{ form_row(AddForm.save) }}

{{ form_end(AddForm) }}
```

Comment: and if you have errors in many tabs form what will you do so ? but to show a bootstrap tab dynamically, I think you  must play with css and class `<div id="tab1" class="{{ form.name1.vars.errors|length ? 'show_class' : 'hide_class' }}` />

Comment: Thanks @hous I'll remember this option for another time, to answer your question there is one form on each tab, so there won't be errors on multiple tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the hash with the third parameter of `createForm method` :

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    \App\Form\Add::class,
    $entityAdd,
    ['action' => '#list-tab1']
);
```

Then, you can use the `setAction()` method and retrieve the option in the `buildForm()` method in your `AddFormType.php` file:

```
$builder
    ->setAction($options['action'])
    ->add(...)
```

Note: Using only the hash in the `setAction()` method (and not the full route), is only working if the form is submitted to the current route.

You'll have to replace `#list-tab1` with the real tab id.

Comment: Good update to your answer. I have multiple forms on the page so I put ['action' => '#tab_name'] on each form, so whichever form (or tab) gets submitted will be open on error since I have return $this->redirectToRoute(...); on success.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the action directly in the parameters of `form_start()`, in the Twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form, { action: '/add#list-tab1' }) }}
```

See the [Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#action) about this field option.

Comment: This is useful to know but not the solution here, that would always load the same tab every page load.